# How do I build persistent Checkout page with Stripe and NextJS(or React)?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-functions, next.js, stripe-payments

In my Nextjs app, I have tried storing the Stripe [`paymentIntent.id`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-id) in the browser `localStorage`  which is then read in the Checkout page. Since, it is stored in `localStorage`, the Checkout page can persistently read the stored `paymentIntent.id` even after page refresh. I have not stored the `client_secret` since the documentation advised against storing [it](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-client_secret).

There is no issue in setting and getting the `paymentIntent.id` to and from localStorage. But when I try to retrieve the client_secret to confirm payment using this payment id, I am getting error

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve(
  'pi_1DpRyD2eZvKYlo2CG4EobdYA'
);
```

Error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'retrieve')`

Perhaps, it is not possible to retrieve paymentIntent object from client? If so, what is the best way to store or retrieve the `client_secret` ?

*Note:* I am creating the paymentIntent using a cloud function trigger when a doc is written to Firestore.

Comment: Can you share complete code? Where is stripe initialized?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes, there is no issue with stripe initialization. I can perform stripe.confirmCardPayment(client_secret) if i pass the client_secret directly. The issue is with retrieving the paymentIntent object and the client-secret

Comment: @RobLjm you can refer this [stripe Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder?client=react), this may be helpful to you

Comment: @UrjaSatodiya Yes I have gone through the custom payment flow integration. But the samples provided don't handle page refreshes

Comment: Have you tried [`retrievePaymentIntent`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/retrieve_payment_intent) which is part of Stripe _client_ JS SDK?

Comment: @Dharmaraj ah correct. Now this retrieve requires client_secret and not the id? I want to retrieve client_secret using the id stored in localStorage

Comment: You need `publishable_key` to retrieve the client_secret. I'm not sure if you can do so using payment_intent ID. Fetching payment intents by ID seems to be a privileged actions for the server side SDK